Символ Юникода не имеет сопоставления в конечной многобайтовой кодовой странице
Пробегаюсь по всем файлам системы через filesystem с помощью range for, выдает

Символ Юникода не имеет сопоставления в конечной странице

На данной строчке кода:
string fileName = entry.path().filename().string();

Где entry - текущий файл/папка
Как решить проблему?

OS какая????????

@avp, windows 10
